# RuntimeError: Language not supported: en_core_web_md in spacy.load

Tags: python, machine-learning, spacy

I am seeing following error when I do

```
import spacy

spacy.load('en_core_web_md en')

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

  File /anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/__init__.py", line 15, in load

    package = get_package_by_name(name, via=via)

  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/util.py", line 41, in get_package_by_name

    lang = get_lang_class(name)

  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/util.py", line 28, in get_lang_class

    raise RuntimeError('Language not supported: %s' % lang)

RuntimeError: Language not supported: en_core_web_md
```

I installled en_core_web_md and see it

```
$ pip freeze

…

en-core-web-md==2.0.0

….
```

Any help? Things to try?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are possibly two problems here:

The first is a typo in the model name you're passing to `spacy.load`: instead of `'en_core_web_md en'`, you likely only want to load `'en_core_web_md'`.

Second, which version of spaCy are you running? The error message shows the usage of functions that I don't even remember – I just had a quick look at the source history, and you might be running a spaCy version as old as <1.0. This means that the models won't be compatible either and the API will differ in various places.

You can upgrade spaCy by running `pip install -U spacy` – although I'd recommend starting with a clean environment and installing everything from scratch to avoid ending up with stale files in your installation. Also make sure that the Python environment you're running is the one with the correct version of spaCy. (For example, it's easy to accidentally run the system Python, which may happen to have an old version installed from years ago.)